# Moving list item that contains a code block in org mode

Tags: org-mode

In the following minimal example:

```
* Heading
- Item Foo
#+BEGIN_SRC sh
echo "Hello World!"
#+END_SRC
- Item Bar
```

It is impossible to move the `bar` item above `foo` using `org-move-item-up`. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible: be careful to indent the code block under the list:

```
* Heading
- Item Foo
  #+BEGIN_SRC sh
  echo "Hello World!"
  #+END_SRC
- Item Bar
```

Comment: Simple indeed. Is there a way to do the indentation automatically?

Comment: Yes, use `org-return-indent`, which is bound to `C-j` (to be confirmed, yet I don't think I overwrote it). its doc says: "Goto next table row or insert a newline and indent. Calls `org-table-next-row' or `newline-and-indent', depending on context."